# Prove that the complex number system does not satisfy three properties

Tags: complex-numbers

From my textbook,

The definition of the order relation denoted by > in the real number system is based upon the existence of a subset $P$ (the positive reals) having the following properties.

i) For any number $a\ne0$, either $a$ or $-a$ but not both belong to $P$

ii)If $a$ and $b$ belong to $P$, so does $a+b$

iii)If $a$ and $b$ belong to $P$, so does $ab$

When such a set $P$ exists we write $a>b$ if and only if $a-b$ belongs to $P$.

Prove that the complex number system does not possess a nonempty subset $P$ having properties i), ii) and iii).

The answer: Assume $i$ is in $P$ $\implies i^2=-1\in P\implies(-1)i\implies-i \in P$, which violates i). And similarly for $-i$

My question: This proves that $i$ and $-i$ cannot be in $P$, but I have trouble showing that a general complex number $a+bi$ cannot be in $P$

Comment: Why do you need to do that?  You only need to show that such a $P$ doesn't exist, and it seems you've done that.

Comment: Can't I have a $P$ with $a+bi$, which satisfies all three properties?

Comment: Note that property (i) doesn't merely need to be satisfied for a given number; it has to be satisfied for *all* numbers $\not= 0$: Either the number has to be in $P$, or its additive inverse is, but not both.  You've shown that there is a number (namely, $i$) for which $P$ does not pass condition (i).

Comment: Otherwise, the positive real integers would qualify: No negative real integer is present, and they are closed over addition and multiplication.  But clearly they don't suffice to represent sign in the complex field!

Comment: @matt This set $P$ has to have all three properties, including the first property which should work for *every* complex number, including $i$. The proof shows that, if the third property also holds, then the first property does not, since the first property does not hold for *every* complex number. It's possible to define certain sets where the first property only holds for certain complex numbers (e.g. if $P$ literally is the positive reals, then ii and iii both hold, and i holds only for real numbers in $\Bbb{C}$), but this doesn't properly satisfy i.

Comment: Thank you. The properties need to be satisfied for _all_ numbers. That makes so much more sense.